# Where can I find the currently closed off area on Strómboli?

Tags: hiking, safety, access-rights, italy

On the Aeolian island of Strómboli, my maps and hiking books indicate and describe trails from both Strómboli town and Ginostra to Pizzo o Sopra la Fossa, similar to the indications on [this sketch](https://www.magmatrek.it/wp-content/uploads/2023/02/cartina-stromboli-ENG.pdf). The [guided tour company Magmatrek](https://www.magmatrek.it/en/hiking-excursions-volcano-stromboli/) has an undated message that "currently", one can go up to the 400 metre viewpoint with a guide or up to the 290 metre viewpoint without one, rendering most of those trails inaccessible even with a guide.  Considering there are multiple trails on both the Ginostra and Strómboli town side of the island, the message on the Magmatrek website is not very clear (and coming from a private company, it's not very authoritative, nor do they have an interest telling people the area accessible without a guide).  They link to [the Italian civil protection department](https://rischi.protezionecivile.gov.it/en/volcanic/volcanoes-italy/stromboli/) for more information, which [states](https://www.iononrischio.gov.it/en/get-ready/volcanoes/stromboli/what-know/):

> There is a trail network on the island that allows you to reach the different elevations of the volcano. The viability of the routes is regulated by Ordinances of the Mayor of Lipari depending on the state of activity of the volcano.

Where can I find the current access restrictions for the islands of [Strómboli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stromboli) and [Vulcano](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vulcano)?  Ideally I'm looking for a map with three zones:

- freely accessible,
- accessible with a licensed guide only, or
- access prohibited.

Is such a map publicly available?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### About Stromboli:

Here is a [link to the Ordinance from the Mayor of Lipari](https://www.notiziarioeolie.it/images/documenti/ordinanza_n_14.pdf) dated April 7, 2023

In short:

1. From Stromboli village you can hike *only with a guide* from 190m to 400m
2. The only path from Stromboli is: "Via Salvatore Di Losa– strada vicinale Parroco– Sentiero Naturalistico–Salita al Vulcano"
3. From Ginostra you can unaccompained go up to 130 m via the "Punta Corvi" path, and with a guide up to 400 m
4. Access is subordinate to the actual level of vulcanological activity
5. Fines up to 500 Euros for violations

So if you want to reach the 400 m threshold, you need a guide. They will tell you if the conditions are good enough to go up there or if you must stop at 190m.

### About Vulcano:

[Link to the Mayor Ordinance](https://cme.ingv.it/statodi-attivita-dei-vulcani-eoliani/archivio-documenti-protezione-civile/ordinanze-sindacali-comune-di-lipari/vulcano/1928-2023-04-23-ordinanza-sindaco-lipari-n17/file)

Main points:

1. Hiking is permitted:

- April 1st - October 20th from 6.30 to 10.30 and from 16.00 to 19.30
- October 21st - March 31st from 7.30 to 19.30

2. There is a traffic light indicating whether you can climb to the crater, considering the actual conditions
3. You cannot walk alone (for safety)
4. Bring water, food, clothes and a FFP2/FFP3 mask
5. Fines up to 500 Euros for violations (videosurveillance is in place).

Apparently no guide is needed.

In the linked PDF you'll find a map of the only allowed path.